# Why the response sends 400 error in post in python?

Tags: python-requests, http-post

I have a problem with python requests:
Actually,I want to create a python code that can log in to my website as a typical user without using web browser and collects all solved problems data source which is written pascal and logs out afterwards it will send collected data to another user account with login and post(that's why I coded it in python,I created code that can do that with selenium but it requires more thing than basic post request)
I created simple python data cloner which is connected with my website which name is "http://algo.ubtuit.uz".Here it is(it has some "print statements" to for debugging):

```
import math
import random
import getpass

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

total = 1
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',

}
loginData = {
    'LoginForm[username]': 'Raximov0005',
    'LoginForm[password]': '12457869',
    'LoginForm[rememberme]': '0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/site/login"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    loginData['_csrf-frontend'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf-frontend'})['value']
    # Login_start
    import time
    i = 1
    progress = ""
    for i in range(21):
        randomDot = random.randrange(1, 2, 1)
        if i % 4 == 0:
            progress = ".   "
        if i % 4 == 1:
            progress = "..  "
        if i % 4 == 2:
            progress = "... "
        if i % 4 == 3:
            progress = "...."
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Attempt to login" + progress, end="\r")
    print(loginData['_csrf-frontend'])
    r = s.post(url, data=loginData, headers=headers)
    responseContent = str(r.content)
    # print(responseContent)
    if ('Incorrect username or password.' in responseContent):
        print('\nLOGIN-ERROR:\nUsername or password is incorrect.Please try again.')
    else:
        if ('<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" style="min-width: 150px">' in responseContent):
            print('\nSuccessfully logged in.')
    time.sleep(1)
    idS = []
    totalRange = 51
    for total in range(totalRange):
        if total < 10:
            url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/problems/mysolution?id=00" + str(total)
        if 10 <= total < 100:
            url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/problems/mysolution?id=0" + str(total)
        if total >= 100:
            url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/problems/mysolution?id=" + str(total)
        getSolution = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        getId = BeautifulSoup(getSolution.content, 'html5lib')
        iD = getId.find_all('table', {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered'})
        start = str(iD).find("<tbody>")
        if start != -1 and str(getSolution.content).find("No results found.") == -1:
            idLength = 1
            idStr = ""
            for idLength in range(6):
                idStr = idStr + str(iD)[start + 22 + idLength]
            idS.append(idStr)
        process = math.ceil(1000 * total / totalRange) / 10
        print("|| Found " + str(len(idS)) + " || Inspected: " + str(total) + " || Progress:" + str(
            math.ceil(process * 10) / 10) + "%", end="\r")
    print(
        "|| Found " + str(len(idS)) + " || Inspected: " + str(total) + " || Progress:" + str(math.ceil(process)) + "%",
        end="\r")
    print("ID task completed (" + str(len(idS)) + " of " + str(
        totalRange) + " is SOLVED and had been ACCEPTED by server)                                  \n", end="\r")
    i = 1
    Source = []
    SourceNumbers = []

    for i in range(len(idS)):
        url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/results/view?id=" + idS[i]
        getSolutionText = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        getSource = BeautifulSoup(getSolutionText.content, 'html5lib')
        Solution = getSource.find('textarea', attrs={'name': 'Task[Source]'})
        SolutionNumber = str(getSolutionText.content).find("task/")
        Contest = str(getSolutionText.content)
        helper = 0
        howmuch = 0
        SourceNumberString = ""
        SourceNumberStringFinal = ""
        while Contest[SolutionNumber + helper] != "<":
            SourceNumberString = SourceNumberString + Contest[SolutionNumber + helper]
            helper = helper + 1
        while SourceNumberString[len(SourceNumberString) - 1 - howmuch] != ">":
            SourceNumberStringFinal = SourceNumberString[
                                          len(SourceNumberString) - 1 - howmuch] + SourceNumberStringFinal
            howmuch = howmuch + 1
        SourceNumbers.append(SourceNumberStringFinal)
        Source.append(str(Solution)[49:(len(str(Solution)) - 11)])
        randomDot = random.randrange(1, 2, 1)
        if i % 4 == 0:
            progress = ".                   "
        if i % 4 == 1:
            progress = "..                  "
        if i % 4 == 2:
            progress = "...                 "
        if i % 4 == 3:
            progress = "....                "
            print("Fetching data" + progress, end="\r")
    print("All data recieved.Done.\nLogout...               ")
    s.close()
with requests.session() as s:
    #url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/site/logout"
    #logOutPost = s.post(url,headers=headers)
    #print("Logout status:" + str(logOutPost.status_code))
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n")
    username = 'demo1'  # input('LOGIN:')
    password = 'password1'  # getpass.getpass('PASSWORD:')
    loginData = {
        'LoginForm[username]': username,
        'LoginForm[password]': password,
        'LoginForm[rememberme]': '0'
    }
    url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/site/login"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    loginData['_csrf-frontend'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf-frontend'})['value']
    # Login_start

    i = 1
    progress = ""
    for i in range(21):
        randomDot = random.randrange(1, 2, 1)
        if i % 4 == 0:
            progress = ".   "
        if i % 4 == 1:
            progress = "..  "
        if i % 4 == 2:
            progress = "... "
        if i % 4 == 3:
            progress = "...."
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Attempt to login" + progress, end="\r")
    r = s.post(url, data=loginData, headers=headers)
    responseContent = str(r.content)
    # print(responseContent)
    if ('Incorrect username or password.' in responseContent):
        print('\nLOGIN-ERROR:\nUsername or password is incorrect.Please try again.')
    else:
        if ('<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" style="min-width: 150px">' in responseContent):
            print('\nSuccessfully logged in. ' + str(r.status_code))
    print('\n' + responseContent)
    print(loginData['_csrf-frontend'])
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        dots = i * "."
    print('START SENDING DATA TO NEW ACCOUNT' + dots, end="\r")
    for dataSendLoop in range(len(idS)):
        time.sleep(1)
        sendDataSettings = {
            'Task[Problem_ID]': SourceNumbers[dataSendLoop],
            'Task[Lang_ID]': 'pascal',
            'Task[Source]': Source[dataSendLoop]
        }
        url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/problems/send?id="+str(SourceNumbers[dataSendLoop])

        #print(SourceNumbers[dataSendLoop] + "|||" + Source[dataSendLoop])
        # print("SENDING " + str(dataSendLoop) + " of " + str(len(idS)) + "|| ID:" + SourceNumbers[dataSendLoop] + "...")
        sendData = s.post(url,data=sendDataSettings, headers=headers)
        print(sendData.status_code)
        # print("\nSTATUS: 200 OK (SENDED SUCCESSFULLY)")
    url = "http://algo.ubtuit.uz/site/logout"
    print("\nDone.   Logout...")
    # logOutPost = s.post(url, headers=headers)
    # print("\n\nAll data send.Thanks for using!\nWALBEGO BY DECTAVIANUS 2020.")
```

but I couldn't fix 400 error in requests.post()
Please help me to figure out this

Comment: which POST is returning a 400?

Comment: logout post is not working correctly, it is returning 400 so I can't logout...

Comment: sorry for replying late

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        csrf = soup.find("input", {'name': '_csrf-frontend'}).get("value")
        data = {
            '_csrf-frontend': csrf,
            'LoginForm[username]': 'test@test.com',
            'LoginForm[password]': 'ksksksks',
            'LoginForm[rememberMe]': ["0", "1"],
            'login-button': ""
        }
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        print(r)
        assert "test@test.com" in r.text


Main("http://algo.ubtuit.uz/site/login")
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: thanks for replying but I have a problem in login , I have an error with logout ;)

Comment: dear "αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη" ,in my python code which is shown above , login request response status code is 200 , but , unfortunately, logout request is not working... status code is 400

Comment: thanks for replying but I have not any problem with login , I have an error with logout ;) ------SORRY FOR WRONG COMMENT!!!